# VSTO (Excel): Getting all named rangeds inside a range

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I have an **Excel worksheet** with a **named range A**, which consists again of several named ranges.
How can I get with VSTO all these named ranges (names), which resides inside the named range A?

*For example here I know A and now I want to get B,C,D,E:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the names collection and look for an Intersect between A.ReferstoRange and all the other defined names ReferstoRange. 
You will need to trap out Names that do not refer to ranges.